# error calling non static method

Tags: php, mysqli

```
public  function upload() {

    try {
        $database_connect = new DatabaseConnect();
        $connection = $database_connect->getConnection();

        $this->populate_database($connection); //line 43
        $connection->close();

        return true;

    } catch (Exception $exp) {
        echo $exp->getMessage();
        return false;

    }

}

private function populate_database(mysqli $connection){
    $query = "insert into bases (img_url) values ($this->image_name)";
    $result = $connection->query($query);

    if (!$result) die($connection->error);

    if (!$this->update_linked_table($connection)) {
        echo "linked table not updated";
    }
}
```

i am calling a private non-static method then why am i getting this error:

> **Fatal error:** 
>   Using `$this` when not in object context in /var/www/html/CocExplore/html5BoilerPlate/php/LocalImage.php on line 43

Comment: provide the code for class `DatabaseConnect`

Comment: The problem is with how you're calling `upload`. Show the code that calls it.

Comment: Sorry if this seems trivial but there are only 29 lines in your example. Can you post line 43?...

Answer (score 0):

Call methods non statically. For example, if you call `YourClass::upload()`, replace it to something like `$class = new YourClass(); $class->upload();`

Comment: Can you explain why, please?